# How to increment duplicate values from 1 to n by criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

let's say I have a list of duplicate values in a column such as:AAABBAACABC. ...AAC. Then I want Excel to Rank respectively the first A as A1,the first B as B1 the second A as A2 and the second B as B2 and so forth until the A(nth) and the B(nth). And any additional A should automatically Rank as A(nth+1). Same thing for B C etc.
note that I should be able to enter any new value such as X that will automatically Rank as X(nth+1) or X1 if it did not exist in the table before.

Hoping that I made myself understood. I am waiting for anyone to help me. VBA or array formulas I have no preference once I can realise what I want.

Note that I found a way by sorting them in accending order but it can't match for any additional value at the end of the data base.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying each row in a column would contain one "rankable" string (e.g. cell A1 is "A", cell B1 is "A"), or are you saying a cell contains a string that you want to rank the characters on (e.g. cell A1 is "AABBCA")?

Comment: Yes exactly. Then in the next row I could rank them from 1 to n (the last one) that is for every criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your data is in Column "A". Enter the formula in Column "B" and copy the formula till the row you want.

```
=A1 & IF(A1="","",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic! I can't believe it. It works exactly how I want it. So Much Thanks @Mrig. I still can't believe that I would find a way without VBA codification to do it.

Comment: Just to inform every one that this is the best answer I have found :=A1 & IF(A1="","",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))